# File upload using ng-file-upload in spring mvc

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, ng-file-upload

I used ng-file-upload for uploading a file, but in my spring mvc controller with **@RequestPart MultipartFile**, the getOriginalFilename() method returns blob not the file name

```
@RequestPart(value = "imageFile", required = false) MultipartFile imageFile
```

The console log for my upload is:

```
{$ngfName: "UI-UX.jpeg", $ngfOrigSize: 133046, size: 6320, type: "image/jpeg"}
```

My file uploads correctly but I don't know why the file name is not correct.

Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: use this @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file String fileName;fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image
```